# Web API resources for global counts - what Restful API to create for that?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

Suppose I have a website with the following menu items on the left site of my page:

```
Jobs        (12)
Users       (3)
News        (5)
Documents   (4)
```

Please note the labels on the right side of the menu. They indicate how much items there are for each resource. So for example, the are currently `3` users and `5` News items etc.

When I create a web API for this, then I treat each item as a separate resource. So in my Web API I would have the basic end points like:

```
(GET) /api/job
(GET) /api/job/{id}
(GET) /api/job/count
(POST) /api/job

(GET) /api/user
(GET) /api/user/{id}
(GET) /api/user/count
(POST) /api/user

etc. etc.
```

Of course also end points for `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

The point here is that I have a `count` endpoint for each resource. So what I could do is call the `count` API for each API resource so I can show that number next to each menu item.

But in this case that means I would have to do 4 separate API calls to get the `count` for each item. And this becomes more when I have more menu items. I don't want to end up with 15 separate calls just to show a label next to each menu item showing how much items each resource has.

What is a good practice to solve this in a good Web API manner? Can I for example create a new end point : `api/MenuCount` that returns all the separate counts in one call?

But then again, having such an API end point isn't really a resource. It only has one purpose, counting the total rows for all other resources.

Or is it still better to call each `count` end point for the API's separately? Eventhough that could mean I have to do 15 separate calls for that?

PS. I am talking about a SPA website.